# Make tab key in Emacs function similar to Notepad++

Tags: emacs, notepad++, verilog

I've been trying to find a way to get my Emacs to function similar to notepad++ when tabbing. Specifically, I want a tab to ALWAYS insert spaces when pressed, regardless of where I am in the file.

Currently, I find that tabs only works in specific situations and even then the amount of space inserted is not consistent.

Ideally, the tab press would function similar to notepad++ with where it stops too. For example, if you hit a tab at space 0, it will enter 4 spaces. If you are at space 1, it will only enter 3 spaces to get to the next tab guide.

I don't know if the issue has to do with me using verilog-mode.el, but I've tried a bunch of different combinations and can't get it to work.

I've uploaded my Emacs settings here in case it helps :

https://github.com/TreverWagenhals/TreverWagenhals/tree/master/Emacs

I'm sorry if this appears as a duplicate question, but I've tried a lot of suggestions on the internet and nothing has done what I want it to.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Just-Spaces.html

Answer (score 0):

By default, pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> makes Emacs indent the current line.  That is, it tries to figure out how far the line should be indented (based on the surrounding lines and any mode-specific indentation settings), and then adds or removes tabs and/or spaces to get to the right indentation level.

If you occasionally find that behaviour useful, you can set the variable `tab-always-indent` to `nil`.  That makes the behaviour of <kbd>TAB</kbd> depend on where in the line point is.  If point is at the beginning of the line, it indents the line as described above, and otherwise it inserts a tab or spaces to get to the next tab stop.  (It uses tabs if `indent-tabs-mode` is `t`, the default, and spaces if it is `nil`.)

If you don't need the indentation behaviour at all, you can rebind the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to `tab-to-tab-stop`, which is normally bound to `M-i`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop)
```

Comment: If you look at my emacs script though, you'll see that I have indent-tabs-mode set to nil in a function that I use for verilog-mode. The behavior still isn't correct though. On some lines, hitting tab won't move over at all (comments). On others, hitting tab moves over more than 4 spaces even though I have tab spaces set to 4. And some do less than 4, but not always to a tab stop point. There must be something configured wrong in my ~/.emacs script, or something wrong with the version of emacs i'm on (23.1.1)

Comment: That's the expected behaviour (more or less): by default hitting tab doesn't insert a tab, but adjusts the indentation of the current line to verilog-mode's idea of how far it should be indented. Try if `M-i` does what you expect the tab key to do - in that case, rebinding should solve the problem.

Comment: Ah okay. That's better, not still quite right. It works in most cases, but in some instances I try it and it inserts a ridiculous amount of spaces, even though the line above it is positioned identically. Like, literally 25 spaces for some reason. But that seems to work in the majority of cases so if there's not an obvious solution for that then I might be content with it now.